# How to aggregate nested values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an existing function that creates a summary object from two arrays (one array is transaction data, the other is master data).

Currently, the returned object contains a sum of the transaction quantity by year and month - example below.

**I'm looking for help to add a sum of sums at the root level for each item** - example also below.

I've reviewed answers for similar questions but wasn't able to find a solution close enough to my use case.

Here's the existing code:

```js
const
    array1 = [{ material: "ABC123", cost: 100 },
              { material: "DEF456", cost: 150 }],
    array2 = [{ material: "ABC123", date: "1/1/20", quantity: 4 },
              { material: "ABC123", date: "1/15/20", quantity: 1 },
              { material: "ABC123", date: "2/15/20", quantity: 3 },
              { material: "ABC123", date: "4/15/21", quantity: 1 },
              { material: "DEF456", date: "3/05/20", quantity: 6 },
              { material: "DEF456", date: "3/18/20", quantity: 1 },
              { material: "DEF456", date: "5/15/21", quantity: 2 }],
    groups = [
        ({ material }) => material,
        _ => 'byYear',
        ({ date }) => '20' + date.split('/')[2],
        _ => 'byMonth'
    ],
    sum = {
        key: ({ date }) => date.split('/')[0],
        value: ({ quantity }) => quantity
    }, 
    result = array2.reduce(
        (r, o) => {
            const temp = groups.reduce((t, fn) => t[fn(o)] ??= {}, r);
            temp[sum.key(o)] ??= 0;
            temp[sum.key(o)] += sum.value(o);
            return r;
        },
        Object.fromEntries(array1.map(({ material, cost }) => [material, { cost }]))
    );

console.log(result);
```

As mentioned above, I would like it to add a "totalSum" key/value at the root level. The result would look like:

```
{
"ABC123": {
    "totalSum": 8,
    "cost": 100,
    "byYear": {
        "2020": {
            "byMonth": {
                "1": {
                    "sum": 5,
                    "max": 4
                },
                "2": {
                    "sum": 3,
                    "max": 3
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually achieve the entire refactoring with a single [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) call, combined with a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of the `master` array to retrieve `cost`.

Adding a total sum is then trivial since you have the all the properties to hand and don't have to remap your aggregated data.

```js
const
  array1 = [{ material: "ABC123", cost: 100, critical: true }, { material: "DEF456", cost: 150, critical: false }],
  array2 = [{ material: "ABC123", date: "1/1/20", quantity: 4 }, { material: "ABC123", date: "1/15/20", quantity: 1 }, { material: "ABC123", date: "2/15/20", quantity: 3 }, { material: "ABC123", date: "4/15/21", quantity: 1 }, { material: "DEF456", date: "3/05/20", quantity: 6 }, { material: "DEF456", date: "3/18/20", quantity: 1 }, { material: "DEF456", date: "5/15/21", quantity: 2 }],

  master = new Map(array1.map(({ material, ...item }) => [material, item])),
  result = array2.reduce((acc, { material, date, quantity }) => {
    let [month, , year] = date.split('/');
    year = '20' + year;

    const
      _material = (acc[material] ??= { ...master.get(material), totalSum: 0, byYear: {} }),
      _byYear = (_material.byYear[year] ??= { byMonth: {} }),
      _byMonth = (_byYear.byMonth[month] ??= { sum: 0, max: 0 });

    _material.totalSum += quantity;
    _byMonth.sum += quantity;
    _byMonth.max = Math.max(_byMonth.max, quantity);

    return acc;
  }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Edit**

In a comment you mentioned that you might have more properties in `array1` that should be included in the final result. I've edited to accommodate this by changing the `Map` to reference the entire object as found in `array1`. We can then include all the properties available using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) when we first declare the relevant object in the accumulator.

```js
// split out 'material' from the rest of the object in the Map
const master = new Map(array1.map(({ material, ...item }) => [material, item]));

// later access the object by material and spread its props into the accumulator object.
_material = (acc[material] ??= { ...master.get(material), totalSum: 0, byYear: {} }),
```